# How to compose sophisticated and smooth animation on Android?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

I'd like to write a animation on Android that animate the entire view with water ripple effect. After some research, I made my first implementation with OpenGL ES 2.0 on a `GLSurfaceView`. I have a fragment shader like this:

```
precision mediump float;        // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a 
                                // precision in the fragment shader.
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;    // The input texture
uniform float u_Time;           // Current time
uniform float u_CenterX;        // Water ripple origin x, in (0, 1)
uniform float u_CenterY;        // Water ripple origin y, in (0, 1)
uniform float u_AspectRatio;    // Aspect ratio of screen
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment

float offset(float waveR, float r)
{
    float HALF_PI = 3.14 * 0.5;

    float WAVE_HEIGHT = 30.0;
    float WAVE_WIDTH = 200.0;

    return r + WAVE_HEIGHT * sin((r - waveR) / WAVE_WIDTH * HALF_PI) * exp(-abs(r - waveR) / WAVE_WIDTH);
}

void main()
{
    float RES = 720.0;
    float R = 0.3;
    float T = 1000.0;

    vec2 st = v_TexCoordinate.st;
    float radius = RES * R;
    vec2 xy = RES * st;
    vec2 center = RES * vec2(u_CenterX, u_CenterY);
    float waveR = 1.5 * RES * u_Time / T;

    vec2 dxy = xy - center;
    dxy.t = dxy.t * (1.0 / u_AspectRatio);
    float beta = atan(dxy.y, dxy.x);
    float r = length(dxy);

    vec2 xy1 = xy;
    float offsetR = offset(waveR, r);
    xy1.s = center.s + offsetR * vec2(cos(beta)).s;
    xy1.t = center.t + offsetR * vec2(sin(beta)).t * u_AspectRatio;
    st = xy1 / RES;

    vec3 irgb = texture2D(u_Texture, st).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(irgb, 1.0);
}
```

However, my animation have several problems. First, it works just fine on just one device. On the other devices, the effect look weird. And also, I have to obtain a drawing cache of my entire view to be able to put it on a `GLSurfaceView`, which is slow (~ 100 ms) so it pauses the previous animation and looks unnatural. Thirdly I have problems on how to make the drawing cache at exactly the same size and position with the original view. It seems that `SurfaceView`s cannot have an alpha value so I even cannot make any workaround by fading in/out the view. I obtained the drawing cache like this:

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

destroyDrawingCache();
buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap selfCache = getDrawingCache();

setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Is there a faster way? Or if the destroy / build step really necessary if I really want the newest updated look of the view?

Overall, what I'd like to ask is, is OpenGL ES 2.0 with `GLSurfaceView` a proper tool to implement such an animation? I checked out some demos of water ripple effect by others (implemented with Java or JNI code without OpenGL), however, I failed to find an implementation which has good performance (some of them has a fps of 3!). And if you'd help me and point out any error in my shader code or my way of getting drawing cache, I would be very appreciate.